# Square Positioning Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

Whats the best practice to handle **constraints** for those **squares** (**green** and **blue** ones)? 
The four, blue ones, are all of the same size.

I've spent some hours trying to get the constraints right, but everytime it doesn't fit for the IPhoneSE and smaller devices.

How to set the constraints here?

[image]

Comment: Use `UIStackView`.

Comment: Do you really need to use Autolayout? Because you could use either `UICollectionView` or `UIStackView` to build a view like yours.

Comment: Do you want the blue squares to **grow** based on the width of the device? Or do you want them to be a fixed size, and have the "grid" centered horizontally?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, they should grow/ shrink. The grid is centered horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want the below way:

1. Use two horizontal `stackviews` to hold 4 `views`.
2. Embed both the `stackviews` into a vertical `stackView`.

[image]

I am attaching an image for your reference:

Hope this helps. For any queries feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thx, I will try it!

Comment: It worked for me, thank you! Never worked with stack views before, wasn't that easy.

Comment: Everything looks hard when trying it for the first time then it becomes easy. :D Happy Coding. Cheers! :D